# Clear upto a specific activity from the stack history

Tags: android

Suppose I have activities named A, B, C, D. Now, consider A has been launched as the root activity and B has been launched from A and C has been launched from B and D has been launched from C. 
Now I have a button named "Success" in the activity D. If suppose, I press the button "Success" in the activity D, then the activity C should be removed from the history stack and go to activity B, but on Pressing back key from the activity D should display activity C instead of B and Clear D from stack. Please can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you organised this in activities, and are all part of a, let's say, step by step which my vary depending on the previous, I strongly believe in the power of `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in your `Activity_D` for `Button` click

```
    btnSuccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity_D.this, Activity_B.class));
            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
```

Also add this in your `Activity_D` to **Handle Back Button Pressed.**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**From Activity_C to Activity_D**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity_C.this, Activity_D.class));
```

Don't call `finish()` here.

Comment: Thanks. But as per your code, the stack is not clearing. and when I click back button from B it will go to activity D. So I hope this will not work for me.

Comment: Have you added `finishAffinity()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Success button, you can use the following line of code to open your B activity:

```
Intent d_intent = new Intent(D.this, B.class);
d_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
d_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(d_intent);
finish();
```

Here Activity B will be started from the back stack rather than a new instance because of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` clears the stack and makes it the top one. So when we press the back button the whole application will be terminated. And on Back press you need to simply call

```
finish();
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. But I need to be like when I click back button from B I need to go to Activity A, Application shouldn't get close.

Comment: In that case, you can try this without **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag